# Wie wähle ich das korrekte Einleitewort eines Relativsatzes?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case

Ich will sagen: "There are many certificat(ion)s, which I would take".

> Es gibt viele Zertifikate, die ich machen will/wollte.

Oder

> Es gibt viele Zertifikate, deren ich machen will/wollte.

Mein Problem liegt bei den Wörtern "die"/"deren". Geht hier Plural Genitiv oder Akkusativ?

Comment: Willkomme bei German Language. Bitte achte darauf, dass der Titel Deiner Frage immer auch die eigentliche Frage enthält. Nur so können auch nachfolgende Besucher noch von der Frage profitieren. Danke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Der grammatische Fall wird vom Verb bestimmt, und dieses fallbestimmende Verb ist »**wollen**«. Jenes Argument von *wollen*, welches beinhaltet was gewollt wird (Das Ziel des Wollens) muss im Akkusativ stehen:

> Er will **dich**.
>   Hans wollte **den Ball**.
>   Der König wird **dein Land** wollen.

Anstelle des Akkusativobjekts kann auch ein Verb im Infinit stehen. In diesem Fall drückt dieses Verb eine Tätigkeit aus, die vom Subjekt gewollt wird:

> Er will **schlafen**.
>   Hans wollte **weggehen**.
>   Der König wird **essen** wollen.

Wenn sowohl ein Akkusativobjekt als auch ein Verb im Infinitiv vorhanden sind, drücken diese beiden gemeinsam nicht nur eine Tätigkeit (durch das Verb) aus, sondern geben auch an, worauf sich diese Tätigkeit bezieht (durch das Akkusativobjekt):

> Er will **ein Haus bauen**.
>   Hans wollte **seine Blumen gießen**.
>   Der König wird **den Feind besiegen** wollen.

Genau in eben dieses Schema fällt auch der Satz:

> Ich will **die Zertifikate machen**.

- Ich = Subjekt
- will = Prädikat
- die Zertifikate = Akkusativobjekt
- machen = Infinitiv-Verb

Der Teil »die Zertifikate« kann unterteilt werden in:

- die = Artikel (Plural, Akkusativ)
- Zertifikate = Nomen (Plural, Akkusativ)

Das Akkusativobjekt »*die Zertifikate*« kann ersetzt werden durch ein Pronomen:

> Ich will **die** machen.
>   Ich will **diese** machen.
>   Ich will **jene** machen.

Beachte, dass im ersten Satz »die« kein Artikel ist, sondern ein Pronomen.

Die drei hier verwendeten Pronomen sind Demonstrativpronomen. Man kann stattdessen aber auch Relativpronomen verwenden, die dann einen Relativsatz einleiten. Um aus einem Hauptsatz einen Relativsatz zu machen, muss die Reihenfolge der Wörter geändert werden (Pronomen an die erste, Verb an die letzte Position), und vor allem muss es davor einen anderen Satz geben, der nun der Hauptsatz ist:

> Es gibt viele Zertifikate, **welche** ich machen will.
>   Es gibt viele Zertifikate, **die** ich machen will.

»Es gibt viele Zertifikate« ist der Hauptsatz, »die/welche ich machen will« ist der Relativsatz, der von einem Relativpronomen (»die« oder »welche«) eingeleitet wird. Dieses Relativpronomen ist ein Stellvertreter für etwas anderes, in diesem Fall für »viele Zertifikate«.

Der grammatische Fall von »viele Zertifikate« wird durch das Verb »gibt« bestimmt, das den Akkusativ verlangt. Der Fall des Pronomens wird von »will« bestimmt, das ebenfalls den Akkusativ verlangt. Diese Übereinstimmung ist zufällig, wie dieses Beispiel zeigt:

> Es gibt viele Zertifikate, **derer** ich mich bemächtigen will.

Hier ist »derer« ein Realtivpronomen im Genitiv, das Stellvertreter für die Zertifikate ist. Ersetzt man dieses Pronomen durch das wofür es steht, dann kann man den Relativsatz in einen Hauptsatz umformen:

> Ich will mich **der Zertifikate** bemächtigen.

Wie schon oben beschrieben, verlangt »will« für sein Objekt den Akkusativ. Dieses Objekt ist das Personalpronomen »mich«, und das steht tatsächlich im Akkusativ:

> Ich will **mich**.

Als weitere Ergänzung gibt es das Verb »bemächtigen«, das im Infinitiv steht, was ich weiter oben schon ausgeführt habe:

> Ich will mich **bemächtigen**.

Aber nicht nur »will« kann durch ein Objekt ergänzt werden, auch an »bemächtigen« kann man ein weiteres Objekt anfügen, jedoch verlangt »bemächtigen« für dieses zweite Objekt nicht den Akkusativ, sondern den Genitiv:

> Werner bemächtigt sich<sub>Akkusativ</sub> **des Geldes**<sub>Genitiv</sub>.
>   Ich bemächtige mich<sub>Akkusativ</sub> **der Zertifikate**<sub>Genitiv</sub>.

In der Konstruktion von oben:

> Ich will mich **der Zertifikate** bemächtigen.

Und wieder als Relativsatz:

> Es gibt viele Zertifikate, **derer** ich mich bemächtigen will.

Comment: Ich finde "bemächtigen" in diesem Kontext eher unglücklich gewählt.

Comment: Vielen Dank für diese umfassende Antwort.